# Google custom search - poor image results

Tags: google-custom-search, google-image-search

I've created a Google Custom Search engine to add an image search functionality in my android app.
In the Google dashboard, I've added `*.google.com` as a website to search in with the aim of propose to the user the same image results he would have found on google from browser.

Below the complete configuration:

- keywords: empty
- edition: free, with ads
- image search: `on`
- speech input: `off`
- language: english
- sites to search: `*.google.com`
- restrictions: empty

The problem is that results are poor and very different from those from google.com.
How should I configure my engine?

Comment: Provide your configuration and implementation and maybe someone can help you. Also provide what you are deeming as "results are poor and very different" for comparison. This question is too vague to be answered as is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a setting in `Site to search` section with the value *search only included sites*. I changed to *entire web* and the results are now similar with the browser version.