# Google custom image search returns bad images

Tags: java, google-chrome

I want to get images from the Google Custom Search API. My problem is that Iam getting very weird images and no matter what I change in the settings.

keywords: empty

edition: free, with ads

image search: on

safe search: off

speech input: off

language: english

sites to search: -

restrictions: empty

search entire web: on

(Sorry if something is wrong translated, my UI is in german).
Some other user also had this problem but his solution didnt help me. [Google custom search - poor image results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217056/google-custom-search-poor-image-results)

So no matter what I change in the settings, Iam getting the same images.
If I search "apfel" (english: apple) Iam getting this image link:
https://scontent-atl3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/31514744_140795226776868_4684314220345425920_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-atl3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_ohc=FdhVBUbROnkAX9AJdVR&oh=ea552d4c8b23acd0a3c82d83632e0895&oe=5ECA7F0E

But when I search it in the UI I get this:
[image]

It should not be the issue but here the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String key = "";
    String cx = "";
    String keyword = "apfel";

    URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" + key + "&cx=" + cx + "&q=" + keyword);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");


    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if(output.contains("\"src\": \"")){                
            System.out.println(output);       //Will print the google search links
        }   
    }
    conn.disconnect();                              
    }
```

Comment: Seems like it's finding the celebrity Iris Apfel, which isn't a bad result.  Can you specify that you are looking specifically for the fruit?

Comment: But the normal google search shows me the apple as a fruit and also Iam doing a programm where the user has to type the word in an box... But the thing is that I can change thousend of things in the settings but the results keep the same...

Comment: It could also be a localization issue.  You are doing a google search in german on google.com, but the api you are calling is presumably doing a search in English.  When I search for Apfel in english I am seeing prominent results of Iris Apfel.

Comment: The results are still trash. They take the worst images they can find I think.